# Xcode swift download binary file from json

Tags: ios, json, xcode, binary

I have json rpc service, one method gives binary file with metadata, for example:

```
{
        id = 1;
        jsonrpc = "2.0";
        result =     {
            anonymized = 0;
            id = 331210;
            logged = 1;
            content = "e1xydGYxXGFkZWZsYW5nM… …AwMDAwMDAwMDAwMH19";
        };
}
```

On client side I can correctly deserialize response by:

```
let responseObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? NSDictionary
```

I can read object result as NSDictionary, but can not find way to save field content to disk as binary file. I did not find any solution.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so `content` looks like it's base64 encoded. If so, you would do it like this:

```
if let encodedData = responseObject?["result"]?["content"] as? String {
    if let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedData, options: nil) {
        data.writeToFile(desiredFilePath, atomically: true)
    }
}
```